# Determining number of zoom levels in spatial tile set?

Tags: leaflet, tiles

I've been given a tile-map as a set of nested folders of image data, to use as a backdrop in a leaflet map.

I need to provide leaflet with the maximum zoom level, so it doesn't try to zoom in too far.

Is it possible to determine the number of zoom levels by inspecting the data?

The top level folder contains folders numbered `0` to `9`.  Is this an indication that the data goes up to zoom level 9?

Comment: Yes, max zoom is then 9.

Comment: Go on Tomazic, add it as an answer - I can mark it as correct and you get all those points :-)

Comment: It's too trivial to make it an answer.